# Is there any API : Device supports/has type C USB port feature or not?

Tags: android

Is there any API  : Device supports/has  type C USB port feature  or not?

Something like this for type C USB port

```
final boolean deviceHasCameraFlag = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
```

Comment: There are no Android APIs that depend on a USB Type C port. What difference does the USB port type make?

Comment: based on USB type i want to guide user to use appropriate USB cable. i was going through /sys/class/android_usb is there any info . No luck

Comment: @KekoTester I have a similar requirement. Did you arrive on a solution?